# PHP Preg_Match in string for blacklist words

Tags: php

I would like to have the code look for wildcards in the preg_match search.  For example, right now it only finds the word Dumps..  If the word is dumpster, I would like for it to be able trigger..

Thanks in advance!

```
$aSpam= array
( 'Cvv'=> ''
, 'Dumps'=> 'i'
, 'acc Paypal'=> 'i'
);

foreach( $aSpam as $sWord=> $sOption )
if( preg_match( '#\\b'. preg_quote( $sWord, '#' ). '\\b#'. $sOption, $message_parser-> message ) ) {
    $error[]= 'Spam detected';
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the last `\\b` from the expression, which indicates a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).